# FSO file rename code running twice

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, file-rename, filesystemobject

**Scenario** - OutFolder contains XML files which are named by their created datetime (like 20140524110115, 20140524110120, 20140524110122 and so on). I want to rename these files based on their ID and Action tag values (and check for duplications too).

**Problem** - When I run the following code, the loop is running twice as many times as number of files in the folder. Currently, the folder contains 67 files and the loop is running 134 times. Hence the files are renamed as

```
ID11_New_2.xml
ID11_Used_2.xml
ID12_New_2.xml
ID12_Sold_2.xml
... and so on
```

I was expecting

```
ID11_New_1.xml
ID11_Used_1.xml
ID12_New_1.xml
ID12_Sold_1.xml
... and so on
```

Why the loop is running twice?

```
Sub Test(OutFolder)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.Async = False
    Set objFiles = objFSO.GetFolder(OutFolder).Files
    i = 1

    For Each FileXML In objFiles
        Debug.Print i
        xmlDoc.Load (FileXML.Path)
        Set varID = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Id")
        Set varAction = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Action")
        If varID.Length > 0 And varAction.Length > 0 Then 'if file is of correct format
            FileCtr = 1
            varFileName = varID(0).Text & "_" & varAction(0).Text & "_" & FileCtr & ".xml"
            'check for duplicates
            While objFSO.FileExists(objFSO.BuildPath(OutFolder, varFileName))
                varFileName = varID(0).Text & "_" & varAction(0).Text & "_" & FileCtr & ".xml"
                FileCtr = FileCtr + 1
            Wend
            'FileXML.Name = varFileName
            With objFSO
                .MoveFile .BuildPath(FileXML.ParentFolder, FileXML.Name), .BuildPath(FileXML.ParentFolder, varFileName)
            End With
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It's a pretty good rule of thumb not to change the content of a set of objects while at the same time iterating over them.  Dump the source file names into a collection first, and then process them.

Answer (score 0):

```
While objFSO.FileExists(objFSO.BuildPath(OutFolder, varFileName))
    FileCtr = FileCtr + 1
    varFileName = varID(0).Text & "_" & varAction(0).Text & "_" & FileCtr & ".xml"
Wend
```

And not really sure if the folder where you test for duplicates is the correct one (i don't know what the folders contain), but maybe in ther first line you need to change `OutFolder` with `FileXML.ParentFolder`

Comment: Didn't work ... still getting the same result. 134 loops and files with _2 names. Before running the macro, folder contains the files with datetime as names. I am hoping to rename these files based on their content (ID and Action) in the same folder. So OutFolder is FileXML.ParentFolder.

Comment: @PankajJaju, as the input and output folders are the same, and as the `.Files` collection is not static (that is, as you rename the files they are included in the collection), you are reprocessing the files. So, use different folders or check if the file has been renamed.